# How to Override Start WinUI 3.0 Desktop Application

Tags: winapi, winui-3

I'm interested in overriding the entry point in my WinUI 3.0 Desktop App to control the message pump. It doesn't appear to be as simple as redefining the static function

```
static auto Start(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallback const& callback);
```

in the applications child class. I'm a bit confused even, if the entry point isn't still wWinMain, because if it is, it isn't defined in the solution. I haven't tried setting the Linker option to some other entry point, because I saw mentioned that doing so skips static member pre-processing, and I figured I'd find out what that meant before I started messing around. So how do I capture the entry point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has probably been generated by the tooling you use. If you don't use any special tooling or/and have chosen a fancy compiler, you should be able to do it yourself.

If you choose Microsoft tooling, typically [C++/WinRT](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt) with C++ and Visual Studio, then WinMain is generated probably in a file named `App.xaml.g.hpp` (to find that, just start debug, it should get you right in that WinMain).

To use your own, define [DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_MAIN](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2022/01/28/making-the-app-single-instanced-part-3/) somewhere (note it works for C# too):

[image]

And add for example this to your appp.xaml.cpp file:

```
int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
  winrt::init_apartment(winrt::apartment_type::single_threaded);

  // put your fancy code somewhere here
  ::winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start(
    [](auto&&)
    {
      // and here (default is like this)
      // ::winrt::make<::winrt::MyNamespace::MyApp::implementation::App>();
    });

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Nothing was including App.xaml.g.hpp so I wasn't looking for it. Neither was find in file. At first I thought you were making stuff up. I've never just stepped into the program. I stepped in and there it was. Thanks!